# MongoError: topology was destroyed, NODEJS

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I am trying out the MongoDB API and I ran into `MongoError: topology was destroyed` while trying to use the `insertOne()` function. I don't know what is going on as I am pretty new to this. Any suggestions or help would be appreciated.

```js
const MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;
const uri = "mongodb+srv://email:password@cluster0.9r3f9.mongodb.net";
const client = new MongoClient(uri, { useNewUrlParser: true });


client.connect(mongoError => {

    const col = client.db("mc").collection("mc").insertOne({"license" : "1", "uuid" : 123})
    console.log(col)

});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `client.connect()` should accept both parameters `error` and `client` and use that object to execute the queries. Also since you are using mongodb driver natively (and not mongoose) you shouldn't need to use `{ useNewUrlParser: true }`.

Even if this doesn't solve the problem, restart your mongodb instance and check.

```
const MongoClient = require("mongodb").MongoClient;
const uri = "mongodb+srv://email:password@cluster0.9r3f9.mongodb.net";
const client = new MongoClient(uri);

client.connect((err, client) => {
  if(err) {
    console.error("ConnectionError::", err);
    return;
  }
  const db = client.db("mc");
  db.collection("mc").insertOne({ license: "1", uuid: 123 }, (err, result) => {
    console.log(result);
  });
});
```

NOTE: `.insertOne()` is an async operation and will require a callback as well or `async/await` to correctly show to results of the query.

Comment: I've tried it out but now it returns `TypeError: Cannot read property 'db' of undefined` at line 6.

Comment: @MaxPan Did u try restarting the mongodb. check if the callback is sending an `error`a dn what is there is `client` object.. have update the code to check the same.